# elementary OS Boot issue

Tags: system-installation, boot, microsoft-windows

[image]

Hi all.    I'm having a common issue but can't find an applicable answer.    I have Windows 10 and trying to add dual boot to elementary OS.   I shrank and partitioned the drive as shown in the image above.   However the computer boots straight into Windows 10.   I am unable to run boot-repair from the elementary OS live demo.   I have elementary OS ISO on bootable USB.  Not sure, do I need to start over?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to change default bootloader to grub.

Enter BIOS setup page and find tab where you can change default bootloader to grub.

Probably right now you have windows boot loader set as default and it's boots automatically Windows.

I had that problem too on few machines.

Answer (score 0):

Hello thanks for your response!

[image]

I can put it on UEFI INT13, which seems to load some sort of Grub off of my USB but it's only install options.     I already installed.

[image]

Comment: What you get here is your pendrive you used to install the system with, which seems to be connected.
Where did you write GRUB while installing?